# How can Spring only select one resource (properties file) when several may exist on the classpath

Tags: spring, spring-security

When configuring Spring security, I'm using the basic in-memory authentication manager which reads credentials from a properties file (`creds.properties`). For example:

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service properties="classpath:creds.properties">
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

My app is delivered with a default file containing a default user, but I would like to have the user provide their own file on the classpath. So, I *could* specify the properties file with a wildcard, like `classpath*:creds.properties`. However, the caveat is that I only want one of the property files to be used (the first one found) and that wildcard is going to pick up all matching files and merge the results. I would only want the creds, provided by the user override, to be in effect.

The Spring docs seem to imply that I could also wildcard the path, Ant-style as `classpath:/**/creds.properties`, but this didn't work for me as none of the files were even found.

How could I achieve this in the above scenario?

I started looking at the `PropertiesFactoryBean`, but it doesn't seem to support my need directly. My use-case might be solved by extending `PropertiesFactoryBean` (which itself extends `PropertiesLoaderSupport`) and overriding `loadProperties` but that also isn't going to work very easily as that class doesn't really seem to be designed to be extended without, basically, copying the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation : **don't use the classpath for configuration discovery**.

I prefer to check for configuration in following order:

1. Check a system property for the location of the configuration file.

   For example: `-Dconfig.file=config.properties`
2. Check a predefined external location for a configuration file with a predefined name.

   For example: `file:/etc/myapp/config.properties`
3. Use a default configuration file from the classpath.

   For example: `classpath:com/myapp/default-config.properties`